# Add on conflict replace to Nhibernate mapping file

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, unique, nhibernate-mapping

i am writing an application in it i am using `NHibernate` with `SQLite`.

i have a table that have a column and i want it be unique and on conflict replace.

this is my `.hbm.xml` mapping file codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="TaxeeManager"
               namespace="TaxeeManager.Database">

  <class name="Office" table="offices">
  <id name="Id" column="id">
  <generator class="identity" />
  </id>

<property name="Name" column="name" />
<property name="Address" column="address" />
<property name="ManagerName" column="managername" />
<property name="Email" column="email" />
<property name="WebSite" column="website" />
<property name="Phone1" column="phone1" />
<property name="Phone2" column="phone2" />
<property name="Phone3" column="phone3" />
<property name="Picture" column="picture" />
<property name="Mid" column="mid" unique="true"/>
<property name="RegisterId" column="registerid" />
<property name="Latitude" column="latitude" />
<property name="Longitude" column="longitude" />

 </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

my unique column is `mid`.

My `table` finally must be like this.

```
CREATE TABLE offices (id  integer primary key autoincrement, name TEXT, address TEXT, managername TEXT, email TEXT, website TEXT, phone1 TEXT, phone2 TEXT, phone3 TEXT, picture TEXT, mid BIGINT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE, registerid TEXT, latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE)
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear Mohammad Reza I think you most create this constraint using pure SQL code by this function :

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("CREATE TABLE offices (id integer primary key autoincrement, name TEXT, address TEXT, managername TEXT, email TEXT, website TEXT, phone1 TEXT, phone2 TEXT, phone3 TEXT, picture TEXT, mid BIGINT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE, registerid TEXT, latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE)").ExecuteUpdate();
```

I hope this help you :)